# How is our distribution of science and mathematics questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Congratulations (belatedly) to Alexandre Eremenko and Conifold on receiving the first [tag badges](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze) (both in [mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics)) on HSM! You guys have been at the forefront of our mathematics branch, and provided loads of useful information over your time here.

I'm going to take the opportunity to segue into another topic - in this case, a large issue that has been apparent for the last few months: we're getting overwhelmed by [mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) questions. Or, put another way, we're getting *underwhelmed*<sup>1</sup> by science questions.

Currently, on [the front page](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions), <sup>8</sup>/<sub>15</sub> of the newest questions are about mathematics. Not all have the [mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag (unnecessary, in some cases), but all 8 are about mathematics. The other 7 are about physics (though a couple have a slightly broader application). The second page shows a similar pattern, though the 7 on *this* page not about mathematics are split between physics and what I would call "general science" questions, such as ones about units.

There's a pattern that can be seen in the choice of tags. Currently, we have 146 questions with the [mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag, with other math questions not using it. We also have 51 [physics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) questions, 38 [biographical-details](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biographical-details) questions, 34 [discoveries](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discoveries) questions, and 30 [astronomy](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy) questions. Add those four up and you have about the same number of questions as use the [mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag.

These are just some of my musings over the past few weeks. I'm curious as to what others think. Are we getting too many mathematics questions and too few science questions, or is the mix we have right now just fine?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> An actual word, according to the spell-checker.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

At this stage we're really just establishing our culture. As long as we remain open and true to the topic of our charter and don't go modding away questions (and thus potential contributors) that tend drift from what would seem to be our *typical* questions, then we should be fine in the long run.